# Opening doors in Kingsmouth

Tags: the-secret-world

I am doing one of the very early quests to find missing townspeople. However, the indicators direct me right to their doorstep, after which I have no idea what to do. There doesn't seem to be any way to open the door, knock on it or break it down. What should I do to start collecting these guys and/or their body count, and complete the quest?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Spoiler warning:

> Most of them are dead. Cycle through the enemy NPCs near the location; one of them will have the missing person's name, and once you've targeted them they'll be checked off your list.